# Why do I have restrictions in Android Studio with c++ support for creating activities?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-activity, android-ndk

i'm a newbie of Android Studio and i'm looking for some help about NDK programming.

Why do I include c++ support, Android Studio does not allow me to open a main activity with Login Aivity or Google Maps Activity or NavgationView, etc?

Is it still possible to handle these activities from an empty activity if they include c++ support?

Thanks in advance,
Enda